# Very confused with format function

Tags: common-lisp

I've been trying to get it right for hours now, I still can't figure it out.
Damn. format function is soooo confusing.

Basically what I need is to convert a list into a string. The list can contain strings, and those strings in the resulting string should be **double escaped**. This is what I mean:

if I have `((one "foo") (two 42))`, the resulting string should be the following:

`"\"((one \\\"foo\\\") (two 42)\""` -  note that the entire string is in double quotes, that's why "foo" has to be wrapped twice.

And I can't crack this one. Someone please help.

Comment: (I am curious about why you want to do that)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`prin1-to-string`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_wr_to_.htm#write-to-string), twice:

```
CL-USER> (prin1-to-string (prin1-to-string '((one "foo") (two 42))))
"\"((ONE \\\"foo\\\") (TWO 42))\""
```

`prin1-to-string` is equivalent to `write-to-string` with `:escape t` so that escape characters are written; but using `prin1-to-string` is nicer than the awkward:

```
CL-USER> (write-to-string
          (write-to-string '((one "foo") (two 42)) :escape t)
          :escape t)
"\"((ONE \\\"foo\\\") (TWO 42))\""
```

You could also use `format` with [`~s`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_cdb.htm) which prints escape characters as if by [prin1](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_wr_pr.htm#prin1), as [@RainerJoswig has pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61906024/very-confused-with-format-function/61906677#comment109495616_61906677):

```
CL-USER> (format nil "~s" (format nil "~s" '((one "foo") (two 42))))
"\"((ONE \\\"foo\\\") (TWO 42))\""
```

Comment: similar using FORMAT: `(format nil "~s" (format nil "~s" '((one "foo") (two 42))))`